# How to use Spring-Data and QueryDSL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

My code looks like this:

```
@Document(collection = "address")
public class Address implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field("address_id")
    private Integer addressId;
}

public interface AddressRepository extends MongoRepository<Address,String> {

}
```

The problem is that the documentation for QueryDSL mentions the morphia @Entity annotation but the Springs docs claim that Spring-Data supports QueryDSL ? The question is: How do I create the QueryDSL artifacts if I'm using Spring-Data  ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution: use @QueryEntity and com.mysema.query.apt.QuerydslAnnotationProcessor